# How to move TextMate 2 output pane to a new window

Tags: macos, textmate-2

So I've been trying TextMate 2 out and one of the changes is split panes. Now when I run rspec tests the output appears in a split pane at the bottom of the screen.

Has anyone figured out how to move this back to a separate window or is it just not possible? I used to move the test output to another screen but I can't figure out is that's possible in the alpha?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this on the terminal:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview htmlOutputPlacement window
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain briefly what the command will do?

Comment: The command is explained here: http://wiki.macromates.com/FAQ/TextMate2ExpertPreferences

Answer (score 4):

This is now in the GUI

`⌘,` → "*Show Command Output*" New window